# React native react-native-paper problem with chips inside a view

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, card, react-native-paper

[image]

I'm having the following problem with the chip inside the View when it has a style.

I tried the same code on snack expo, there problem doesn't happen.

Expo:

[image]

But when I try it on my physical device I get the problem seen in the picture.

Can you give me a hand?

Link: [expo](https://snack.expo.dev/K7ziSejWH)

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

import { Card, Chip } from 'react-native-paper';

const navigationView = () => <View style={{ margin: 5, marginTop: 50 }} />;

export default function App() {
  const drawer = useRef(null);

  return (
    <DrawerLayoutAndroid
      ref={drawer}
      drawerWidth={300}
      renderNavigationView={navigationView}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          style={{
            flex: 1,
          }}>
          <Card style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
            <Card.Title
              title={'Title'}
              subtitle={'SubTitle'}
              subtitleNumberOfLines={2}
            />
            <Card.Content>
              <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
                <Chip
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#F0BF05',
                  }}>
                  Right
                </Chip>
              </View>
              <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
                <Chip
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
                  }}>
                  Left
                </Chip>
              </View>
              <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
                <Chip
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#F0BF05',
                  }}>
                  Right
                </Chip>
              </View>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue, my solution was to set the flexDirection to row I.e:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Chip
    style={{ backgroundColor: '#00BFFF' }}>
    Left
  </Chip>
</View>
```

I am not 100% sure why this worked for me

Comment: The problem has apparently been fixed with the latest version.

Comment: I actually tried the latest version too, and it was still an issue for me unfortunately

Comment: Look: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/3916  Use alignItems: 'flex-start' or alignItems: 'flex-end'